# php Exec explode array

Tags: php, foreach, exec, explode

Why is the following not working.

```
$directory = './';
exec('ls -loh ' . $directory, $directory_list);
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($directory_list as $file) {
    $x = explode(' ', $file);
    echo '<li>' . $x[3] . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

If i do not explode and i just do `echo '<li>'.$file.'</li>';` then i get a string like this per li
`drwxr-xr-x 10 user 4.0K Sep 8 16:06 _test`

I"m trying to get only the size and not the whole string. What am i doing wrong.

Comment: are you splitting your string by double space

Comment: You are aware that PHP has [filesystem functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php), aren't you

Comment: what result u u getting for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the sizes of the file,try this:

```
exec("ls -sh ./", $results);
foreach(array_slice($results,1,count($results)) as $file) {
    echo $file . "\n";
}
```

Here's my output:

```
4.0K 24
   0 BookingTest.php
   0 date
4.0K date.php
4.0K exec2.php
4.0K somefile
4.0K file.php
4.0K file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use PHP for that:

```
$files = glob("./*");
$files = array_combine($files, array_map("filesize", $files));
```

Which gives you a nice associative array like:

```
[./curl.php] => 1499
[./db.php] => 10267
```

Comment: Thanks, That works perfectly, but i wanted to know why exec was not working.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that you are doing something wrong - your approach is perfectly acceptable. However, if you want to avoid the `explode()` you could do something like:

```
$directory = './';
exec('ls -loh | awk \'{print $4}\'' . $directory, $directory_list);
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($directory_list as $file_size) {
    echo '<li>' . $file_size . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```